# Create a type from object keys dynamically

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an icon-Map.json which is being created dynamically. Example:

```
const iconMap = {
    angleDoubleRight: 'angleDoubleRight.svg',
    angleRight: 'angleRight.svg',
    assets: 'assets.svg',
    barChart: 'barChart.svg',
    cancel: 'cancel.svg',
    chevronDown: 'chevronDown.svg',
    dotChart: 'dotChart.svg',
    dotMenu: 'dotMenu.svg',
    horizontalDots: 'horizontalDots.svg'
    ...

};
```

- I can't create an interface manually from this object because I'm creating it dynamically so I can't use keyof.
- Eventually, I want to create a type of iconMap's keys which I can use outside a component and it will strict my input to iconMap's keys only. (union or enum):

```
 type IconMapMember = 'angleDoubleRight' | 'angleRight' | 'assets' | ....
```

Comment: Type is a static concept. Let's assume that you somehow defined your type like: `type IconMapMember = 'angleDoubleRight' | 'angleRight'|... ` then what are you going to do after adding a new property to the `iconMap` object? Types cannot be modified in runtime, they are for compile time.

Comment: This all comes down to what you mean by "dynamically".  If you mean "at runtime", then you can't do much.  If you mean "programmatically in some build step that occurs before the TypeScript compiler runs", or even "in some other user-written code that the compiler can see", then you can do something about it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your question you say you can't use `keyof`, but I'm not sure why.  If you have an object whose keys are known at compile time (meaning that the `iconMap` variable is generated *before* you compile TypeScript code that uses it), you can use the `typeof` [type query operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10) to get its type, and then use `keyof` on that:

```
const iconMap = {
  angleDoubleRight: "angleDoubleRight.svg",
  angleRight: "angleRight.svg",
  assets: "assets.svg",
  barChart: "barChart.svg",
  cancel: "cancel.svg",
  chevronDown: "chevronDown.svg",
  dotChart: "dotChart.svg",
  dotMenu: "dotMenu.svg",
  horizontalDots: "horizontalDots.svg"
  //...
};

type IconMapMember = keyof typeof iconMap;
// type IconMapMember = "angleDoubleRight" | "angleRight" | "assets" | "barChart" 
// | "cancel" | "chevronDown" | "dotChart" | "dotMenu" | "horizontalDots" ...
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlqMBZAhgBxgXhgbwFAwwpgDmANgKYAiIArgEaUBKcJAFlAFwwBEx51Oowot2UAHQQAbiR4AaAkVLNWHbn2UjVE6bIWEUECBSgR1h46ckz5i+igBOAYTaOuve89cOdN-TGBiYAoydUCwYLJrPUVgNgopB3AaAHcwMPjE5JA06NtCABMQKBc3dSKS718YwuKkCjBacrqG2jz-NhAHOAAvcCgUMhpTdU7uvrABoeKIPMUAennxZbwAXwBuPDwoAE80ChgASURUNHqAW3oKBywYAGsKHZAAMxhd-Zf4E-RNxbe9g7HcCnC5XG7YDQCGgMFRiHgwAA+vH4sI48KRfCMJgg6I8jlKPnheD+GPCkVxPDiCSSYFSYApFQJUAZLUaFLGvX6g2GOJgy3EeCAA)

If you have some particular issue which prevents this solution from working, please update your question with more details about your build process.  Hope this helps; good luck!

Comment: You are right, I was having troubles cause I got iconMap object as a JSON.. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. ```keyof typeof constant``` is what I was looking for!

Comment: I wish to do the same, but not for an object but a type instead, doesn't seem possible.